# rotated div with perspective css3

Tags: html, css

i have a 45 deg rotated div. i am trying on hover to rotate it around its y-axis by using css3 perspective. it dont hover like i want and it becomes a square when hovered. i would like to maintain rotated 45 deg at the end of the animation.

here is my code:

```
<div class="perspective">
   <a href="#" class="box">
      <div class="innerbox">
            text
      </div>    
   </a>
</div>

.perspective
{
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin:200px 0px 0px 200px;
    -moz-perspective: 300px;
    -webkit-perspective: 300px;
    -o-perspective: 300px;
    -ms-perspective: 300px;
    perspective: 300px;
}

.box
{
    width:80px;
    height:80px;    
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
    border: 5px solid #000;
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 800ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 800ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 800ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 800ms ease;
    transition: all 800ms ease;
}

.innerbox
{
    margin:30px 0px 0px 20px;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);  
}

.box:hover
{
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 800ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 800ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 800ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 800ms ease;
    transition: all 800ms ease; 
}
```

i made an example http://jsfiddle.net/o6mo0rjq/

Comment: try by adding this css ==>transform: rotateZ(405deg);I dont thing your task is possible by rotating using Y axis

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp  this link will help you more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've initially rotated `.box` by 45 degrees around the Z-axis. When you specify a new `transform`, this initial rotation is overwritten - so for the new rotation on `:hover`, you should also specify the original rotation. Your block declaration would then become:

```
.box:hover {
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(45deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(45deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 800ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 800ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 800ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 800ms ease;
    transition: all 800ms ease;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o6mo0rjq/32/) to demonstrate. (Note: The order in `transform` matters! Because that dictates the order in which the rotations are applied to the element, which may give you different results depending on the transformations you're applying.)

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Happy I could help you out!